# Is android getting a jit compiler soon?

Tags: android, jit, dalvik, nexus-one

I've read that there is a jit compiler module for dalvik vm on the works and the results are quite promising. Some people claim an improvement of 100% in terms of execution speed. Does anyone have an idea when it is going to be incorporated in an android release? The amount of RAM on the nexus one (512MB) hints that a jit may be introduced soon. Android 2.5 maybe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting it all wrong :) There is a JIT in the work, and it is not RenderScript. RenderScript is something totally different.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the [definitive post](http://groups.google.com/group/android-platform/browse_thread/thread/331d5f5636f5f532) on the subject from the android-platform mailing list:

> **Dalvik JIT Compiler**
>
> As some of you have noticed, the latest Android Open Source Project 
>   tree (eclair) includes source code for a Dalvik JIT compiler.  The 
>   Dalvik team has been actively investigating what kind of JIT would 
>   work best over a wide range of memory- and power-constrained portable 
>   Android devices, and the code in AOSP master is an old snapshot of 
>   what we consider a promising proof-of-concept.  It is a trace-based 
>   JIT, compiling only hot code traces rather than method-at-a-time 
>   strategy typically found on server-class JITs.  It attempts to 
>   minimize heap usage, and it requires no persistent storage.  The goal 
>   is to give a quick performance boost using very little heap and 
>   battery.
>
> The JIT has progressed significantly since the snapshot in AOSP 
>   eclair, and we're working on pushing out a more current version. 
>   Meanwhile, if you'd like to play with the prototype, you can build it 
>   by creating a buildspec.mk file in your AOSP root which includes the 
>   line "WITH_JIT := true".
>
> Note that the prototype JIT had not been extensively tested at the 
>   time the snapshot was taken, so you can expect some breakage.  Also, 
>   it contains few optimizations other than the basic elimination of the 
>   interpreter's fetch/decode cycle.  We're looking forward to getting a 
>   newer version into the AOSP tree.
>
> Bill Buzbee, Ben Cheng & the rest of the Dalvik team

Answer (score 0):

In May 2010, Google posted a blog entry about the addition of JIT to the Dalvik VM:

[Dalvik JIT announcement from Google](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/dalvik-jit.html)